# Is saving a binary file a standard? Is it limited to only 1 type?

Tags: c, memory-management, binaryfiles

When should a programmer use `.bin` files? (practical examples).

Is it popular (or accepted) to save different data types in one file?

When iterating over the data in a file (that has several data types), the program must know the exact length of every data type, and I find that limiting.

Comment: You could create a self describing binary file, e.g. by adding a tag to identify the data type, and a lenght to know the length of the data/field/entry. There's nothing inherent about binary files that requires it to be fixed type/lengths.

Comment: @nos that's a great idea I haven't thought of, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean for some idealized general purpose application data, text files are often preferred because they provide transparency to the user, and might also make it easier to (for instance) move the data to a different application and avoid lock-in.

Binary files are mostly used for performance and compactness reasons, encoding things as text has non-trivial overhead in both of these departments (today, perhaps mostly in size) which sometimes are prohibitive.

Comment: For example Open Document Format works around the "text is big" issue by encoding documents as text and then zipping them for storage. So the saved files have most of the benefits of a binary format and most of the benefits of a text format, but not all the benefits of either.

Answer (score 1):

Binary files are used whenever compactness or speed of reading/writing are required.

Those two requirements are closely related in the obvious way that reading and writing small files is fast, but there's one other important reason that binary I/O can be fast: when the records have fixed length, that makes [random access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access) to records in the file much easier and faster.

As an example, suppose you want to do a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) within the records of a file (they'd have to be sorted, of course), without loading the entire file to memory (maybe because the file is so large that it doesn't fit in RAM). That can be done efficiently only when you know how to compute the offset of the "midpoint" between two records, without having to parse arbitrarily large parts of a file just to find out where a record starts or ends.

(As noted in the comments, random access can be achieved with text files as well; it's just usually harder to implement and slower.)

Comment: Provided you only have to parse limited-size parts of a file to find out where a record starts or ends (for example UTF-8 text), then you can still do a binary search -- you chop in half by bytes rather than by records, so you get `O(k log n)` where `n` is the size of the data and `k` is the max distance searched to find a record start (hopefully the max size of a record). All that matters is whether records are fixed-size or not, not text vs binary. In common with most text files, also most binary files are *not* a sorted array of fixed-length records.

Comment: So I sort of agree with "text files are generally used for variable-length records", but I don't agree with "by contrast", because binary files are generally used for variable-length records too. There is an issue that if you open a file in text *mode*, then you can't seek to arbitrary offsets in it.

Comment: @SteveJessop: hedged the answer a bit. Binary search is just an example; of course, on-disk hash tables require random access as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think when embedded developers see a ".bin" file, it's generally a flattened version of an ELF or the like, intended for programming as firmware for a processor.  For instance, putting the Linux kernel into flash (depending on your bootloader).

As a general practice of whether or not to use binary files, you see it done for many reasons.  Text requires parsing, and that can be a great deal of overhead.  If it's intended to be usable by the user though, binary is a poor format, and text really shines.

Where binary is best is for performance.  You can do things like map it into memory, and take advantage of the structure to speed up access.  Sometimes, you'll have two binary files, one with data, and one with metadata, that can be used to help with searching through gobs of data.  For example, Git does this.  It defines an [index format](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt), a [pack format](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/pack-format.txt), and an [object format](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#object-details) that all work together to save the history of your project is a readily accessible, but compact way.